# Oxygenated hemoglobin in MRI

Tags: neuroscience, brain, blood-circulation, mri

I have read the following sentence:

> Because this oxygenated hemoglobin is unaffected by magnetic fields,
>   the response RF signal returned to the fMRI scanner is stronger when
>   there is more brain activity and therefore more oxygenated hemoglobin
>   in that brain tissue.

Oxygenated hemoglobin does not react to magnetic fields, while deoxygenated hemoglobin does. So in my view, if there is more brain activity and therefore more oxygenated hemoglobin, the signal should be weaker because the oxygenated hemoglobin does not react to the magnetic field? Why is it the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the type of fMRI you are referring to is blood-oxygenation-level-dependent fMRI or  [BOLD fMRI](http://www.nature.com/milestones/milespin/full/milespin19.html).

The principle behind MRI in general is the detection of proton signals from water molecules. The proton signal is generated by magnetizing the protons in tissue, which causes their spin to change. A subsequent powerful radio wave disrupts this spin and the following relaxation phase of the protons to the original state can be detected by MRI. Water, and hence protons are everywhere in the body, including the brain and the blood.

Deoxygenated hemoglobin (hemoglobin without oxygen) in blood changes the proton signal in its immediate surroundings due to the magnetic properties of deoxyhemoglobin. This is caused by the fact that deoxygenated hemoglobin is paramagnetic and **decreases the proton signal**. In fact, the *paramagnetic influence of deoxyhemoglobin has been regarded as noise in structural MRI scans*, before its use in BOLD-fMRI became clear. Oxygenated hemoglobin does not have this property.

[Radiopaedia](http://radiopaedia.org/articles/bold-imaging) has a nice explanation as to exactly how the BOLD signal is used in BOLD fMRI, and I quote:

> When a specific region of the cortex increases its activity in response to a task, the extraction fraction of oxygen from the local capillaries leads to an initial drop in oxygenated haemoglobin [...]. Following a lag of 2-6 seconds, cerebral blood flow (CBF) increases, delivering a surplus of oxygenated haemoglobin, **washing away deoxyhemoglobin** and with it the attenuating effect on the MRI signal. It is this large rebound in local tissue oxygenation which is imaged, as it is accompanied by an **increase in the MRI signal**. The difference is used to generate the BOLD fMRI response.

So brain activity increases the BOLD signal by picking up oxygen-changes after an increased blood flow to that specific part of the brain.

So your statement `[...] If there is more brain activity and therefore more oxygenated hemoglobin the signal should be less strong because the oxygenated hemoglobin does not react to the magnetic field` is incorrect, because oxyhemoglobin attenuates the proton signal.